# Cut edge, cut vertex definition clarification

Tags: graph, graph-theory, definition

Looking some definition clarification for a simple problem. Consider the graph:
A---B where A and B are vertices and there is a single edge between them. Would the edge between them be considered a "cut edge" because its removal disconnects the graph? Or does a "cut edge" necessitate increasing the number of *connected* components, and not just components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is a cut edge. Lets go little deeper in the definitions.

Definition of **cut edge**:

> In **graph theory**, a **bridge**, **isthmus**, **cut-edge**, or **cut arc** is an edge of a **graph** whose deletion increases its number of connected components.

See the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(graph_theory)) article related to cut edge.

Definition of **connected component**:

> In graph theory, a **connected component** (or just **component**) of an undirected graph is a subgraph in which any two vertices are connected to each other by paths, and which is connected to no additional vertices in the supergraph.

See the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) article related to connected component.

An alternative way to define **connected components** involves the equivalence classes of an **equivalence relation** that is defined on the vertices of the graph. In an undirected graph, a vertex v is reachable from a vertex u if there is a path from u to v. In this definition, a ***single vertex is counted as a path of length zero***, and the same vertex may occur more than once within a path. Reachability is an equivalence relation, since:

1. It is **reflexive**: There is a trivial path of length zero from any vertex to itself.
2. It is **symmetric**: If there is a path from u to v, the same edges form a path from v to u.
3. It is **transitive**: If there is a path from u to v and a path from v to w, the two paths may be concatenated together to form a path from u to w.

The connected components are then the induced subgraphs formed by the equivalence classes of this relation.

**Conclusion:**
Single vertex which has no any connection is a connected component based on reflexiveness. Your graph has 1 connected component before edge removal and has 2 connected components without the edge, so your edge is a cut edge.